# wordpress обновление данных

Tags: wordpress

Ребята помогите пожалуйста с обновлением данных в своей таблице данных вордпресс ?
Я не могу понять сам синтаксис, данныне забираю с json потом сразу вставляю в поля данных, но как их обновлять я понять не могу.
Вот нашол универсальеый способ с json вставлять данные insert в таблицу, но как их обновить то ? Получать получаю а обновить никак не могу
Пример кода которые забирает данные в таблицу

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name_1 = $wpdb->prefix.'site';
foreach( $p2 as $i => $id) {
$site = $wpdb->insert(
$table_name_1,
array(
'id' => $p2['user'],
'count' => $p2['count'],
'total' => $p2['total'],
'ttl' => $p2['ttl'],
'tagType' => $p2['tagType'],
'tagName' => $p2['tagName'],
'isUser' => $p2['isUser'],
'userType' => $p2['userType'],
)
);
}
if (!$site) {
print 'There was a error site';
}
```

Как обновлять ячейки count и total ?

Comment: Обновление делается через `$wpdb->update`. Метод принимает на вход название таблицы, в которую вносятся изменения, параметры, которые нужно изменить, и условие, по которому производится выбор строк из таблицы в виде массива (например `[id => 1]`). [Подробнее можете почитать здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb-update)

Comment: Да. я это и раньше видел. спасибо